# Batch replace first 2 characters

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am having this example of a file

```
CM2345
CLMX2345
CLMR5254
CYLR5121
CL2135
MADX5321
MD2145
MADR1234
CYLX1234
```

What i need  to do is to replace all lines in the file starting with

```
md -> MADR
cl -> CYLR
cm -> CLMR
```

The problem comes in when replacing cl, since clmx and clmr also start with cl.

This is how i did it in linux, now i need it in windows batch

```
for file in *.db; do

while read p; do

if  [[ "$p" == CL* ]] && [[ "$p" != CLM* ]] ;
then
r=$(echo $p | sed 's/..//')
echo $r > c.l

while read line
do
echo "CYLR$line" >> $file
done <c.l


fi

done <"$file"
wait

done
```

Thank you !

Comment: There is a tool called `sed` and another one called `awk`, both can do what you want.

Comment: Also, consider showing what you are already trying.

Comment: well i need to run this in windows batch. in linux i did it with sed and i append the new entries to the end of file.

Comment: You can use MSYS to be able to use the same Linux commands in Windows. Or if you will be needing a lot of batch scripting, you can use Perl or Python in Windows as well.

Comment: hmm interesting i will try that. but for now i need the batch version, as this code is just a small part of a bigger batch script

Comment: hm i just find an easy way via powershell (Get-Content test.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "foo", "bar" } | Set-Content test2.txt

Comment: Nice, you could add that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. Do you want to replace the strings *only* in 6-character lines or in lines which don't already start with your "transform-to" string? Do you need to preserve the sequence of lines?

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understand exactly what you are asking me? Preserving the sequence is not a must

Answer (score 0):

Ok i am not sure how to check if it starts with clmx or clmr and not replace the cl for these lines, and i actually don't have time for this. What i did is a trick where i am first replacing all entries and then fix the wrong ones

```
(Get-Content .\t.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "cl", "cylr" } | Set-Content .\t.txt
(Get-Content .\t.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "md", "madr" } | Set-Content .\t.txt
(Get-Content .\t.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "cm", "clmr" } | Set-Content .\t.txt
(Get-Content .\t.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "cylrMX", "clmx" } | Set-Content .\t.txt
(Get-Content .\t.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "cylrMr", "clmr" } | Set-Content .\t.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer doesn't meet your "lines starting with" requirement.  Sounds like `sed` really would be the best tool for the job.  You can get [GnuWin32 `sed.exe`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) and use that to perform your replacements.  By the way, that shell script in your question could be shortened to a one-liner by allowing `sed` to read and modify your files inline like this:

```
sed -i -r -e '/^CLM/! s/^CL/CYLK/ig' -e 's/^CM/CLMR/ig' -e 's/^MD/MADX/ig' *.db
```

(If you'd like to use that line in Windows, replace the single quotes with double to prevent `cmd` from interpreting the carats as escape characters.)

If you don't wish to use GnuWin32 `sed`, then realize that regexp support in Windows batch is pretty weak.  There's `findstr`, but it only supports the most basic regexp matching, and doesn't do replacements.  (It's like a really weak `grep`.)

If you want a solution you can stick in a `.bat` file and run it, then I suggest a batch / JScript hybrid script, something like this:

```js
@if (@a==@b) @end /* begin JScript hybrid multiline comment

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (*.db) do (
    cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%%~I"
)

goto :EOF

:: end batch / begin JScript */

var fso = new ActiveXObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    forReading = 1,
    dbFile = WSH.Arguments(0),
    oldFile = dbFile.replace(/\.\w+$/, '.old');

fso.MoveFile(dbFile, oldFile);

var reader = fso.OpenTextFile(oldFile, forReading),
    writer = fso.CreateTextFile(dbFile);

while (!reader.AtEndOfStream) {
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    writer.WriteLine(line.replace(
        /^(md|cl|cm)(?!mx|mr)/ig,
        function(match, $1) {
            return {
                md: 'MADR',
                cl: 'CYLR',
                cm: 'CLMR'
            }[$1.toLowerCase()];
        }       // end function
    ));         // end replace() and WriteLine()
}               // end while

reader.Close();
writer.Close();

// uncomment if you don't wish to keep backup as .old
// fso.DeleteFile(oldFile);
```

If the strings you want to replace are always two alpha characters followed by numerals, then I suggest replacing the regexp above with `/^(md|cl|cm)(?=\d)/ig` to look ahead for (but not include) a number as the 3rd character of the line.

How good are you at JavaScript?  If you are comfortable with JavaScript, you'll (hopefully) find that JScript easy to follow and maintain as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial problem if you can do all the substitutions in one pass. Easily done using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs a regular expression search and replace on text data. [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

I use the `/T` option to translate a series of search terms into a series of replace terms. The `/I` option ignores case, and the `/B` option forces each term to only match the beginning of a line (easier than including `^` with each term). The `/F` option specifies the source file, and the `/O` option with a `-` value causes the output to replace the original file.

```
jrepl "MD CL CM" "MADR CYLR CLMR" /i /t " " /b /f test.txt /o -
```

If used within a batch script, then you must use CALL since JREPL is also a batch script.

**UPDATE**

If lines are not supposed to be changed if they already start with one of the target strings, then only a minor change is needed:

```
jrepl "MD CL(?!MR) CM" "MADR CYLR CLMR" /i /t " " /b /f test.txt
```

Comment: Can `jrepl.bat` exclude replacing `CLMX` / `CLMR`? According to the top code block in the main question, the example file may already contain those strings, and they need not to be changed. Maybe add replacements for `cylrmx` and `cylrmr` to your solution to duck punch the erroneous matches.

Comment: @rojo - No problem. I had a different interpretation of the problem. I thought the OP was having problems doing the search/replace in stages when one of the target strings matched a different search string, such that the same line could be modified twice. My original answer avoids that problem. I added a second solution that does not change a line if it already matches one of the target strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Batch file program that solve your problem as you stated it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the set of replacements:
for %%a in ("md=MADR" "cl=CYLR" "cm=CLMR") do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do set "replace[%%b]=%%c"

rem Define the values to preserve:
for %%a in (CLMX CLMR) do set preserve[%%a]=1

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /F "tokens=1,2" %%b in ("!line:~0,4! !line:~0,2!") do (
      if not defined preserve[%%b] if defined replace[%%c] set "line=!replace[%%c]!!line:~2!"
   )
   echo !line!
)) > output.txt
```

Output example:

```
CLMR2345
CLMX2345
CLMR5254
CYLR5121
CYLR2135
MADX5321
MADR2145
MADR1234
CYLX1234
```